# Unable to destroy activity LocationTrack.stopListener()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my android app I am getting GPS location in splash screen and storing in a session. In my fragment based on location I am fetching the data from database, if user wants to change the location on click action bar its going to `SelectLocationActivity` there is button detect my location.

If user clicked on button its getting the location and storing in session, but if uses click on back button with out doing any action on Activity, my app is getting crashed with error unable to destroy activity.

my code:

```
public class SelectLocationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button detcbtn;

private Session session;

private ArrayList<String> permissionsToRequest;
private ArrayList<String> permissionsRejected = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<String> permissions = new ArrayList<>();

private final static int ALL_PERMISSIONS_RESULT = 101;
LocationTrack locationTrack;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.selectlocation);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.stoolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

    session = new Session(SelectLocationActivity.this);

    detcbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.find_location);

    detcbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            permissionsToRequest = findUnAskedPermissions(permissions);
            //get the permissions we have asked for before but are not granted..
            //we will store this in a global list to access later.

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                if (permissionsToRequest.size() > 0) {
                    requestPermissions(permissionsToRequest.toArray(new String[permissionsToRequest.size()]), ALL_PERMISSIONS_RESULT);
                } else {
                    SetUserLocation();
                }
            }else{SetUserLocation();}

        }
    });

}

public void SetUserLocation() {
    locationTrack = new LocationTrack(SelectLocationActivity.this);

    if (locationTrack.canGetLocation()) {
        double longitude = locationTrack.getLongitude();
        double latitude = locationTrack.getLatitude();

        Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(SelectLocationActivity.this, Locale.getDefault());
        List<Address> addresses = null;
        try {
            addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
            String locality = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
            String subLocality = addresses.get(0).getSubLocality();
            String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
            String state = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
            String countryn = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
            String postalCode = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
            String knownName = addresses.get(0).getFeatureName();


            session.setLocation(latitude, longitude, locality, subLocality);

            Toast.makeText(SelectLocationActivity.this,locality +" "+ subLocality, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } else {
        locationTrack.showSettingsAlert();
    }
    //go to main activity
    SetLocation();
}

public void SetLocation(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(SelectLocationActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}

///GPS Tracker
private ArrayList<String> findUnAskedPermissions(ArrayList<String> wanted) {
    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (String perm : wanted) {
        if (!hasPermission(perm)) {
            result.add(perm);
        }
    }

    return result;
}

private boolean hasPermission(String permission) {
    if (canMakeSmores()) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            return (checkSelfPermission(permission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
        }
    }
    return true;
}

private boolean canMakeSmores() {
    return (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1);
}


@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {

    switch (requestCode) {

        case ALL_PERMISSIONS_RESULT:
            for (String perms : permissionsToRequest) {
                if (!hasPermission(perms)) {
                    permissionsRejected.add(perms);
                }
            }

            if (permissionsRejected.size() > 0) {


                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(permissionsRejected.get(0))) {
                        showMessageOKCancel("These permissions are mandatory for the application. Please allow access.",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                                            requestPermissions(permissionsRejected.toArray(new String[permissionsRejected.size()]), ALL_PERMISSIONS_RESULT);
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                        return;
                    }else{SetUserLocation();}
                }
            }else{SetUserLocation();}
            break;
    }

}

private void showMessageOKCancel(String message, DialogInterface.OnClickListener okListener) {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(SelectLocationActivity.this)
            .setMessage(message)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", okListener)
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
            .create()
            .show();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    locationTrack.stopListener();
}

@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    onBackPressed();
    return true;
}
}
```

on back button click its going to my fragment. do i need to create any `OnResume` method in my fragment?

please see error report

```
06-16 12:21:28.061 22173-22173/zesteve.com.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           Process: zesteve.com.myapplication, PID: 22173
                                                                           java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity {zesteve.com.myapplication/zesteve.com.myapplication.SelectLocationActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void zesteve.com.myapplication.location.LocationTrack.stopListener()' on a null object reference
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3861)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3879)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:166)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1414)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5468)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void zesteve.com.myapplication.location.LocationTrack.stopListener()' on a null object reference
                                                                               at zesteve.com.myapplication.SelectLocationActivity.onDestroy(SelectLocationActivity.java:189)
                                                                               at android.app.Activity.performDestroy(Activity.java:6793)
                                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnDestroy(Instrumentation.java:1143)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3848)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3879) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:166) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1414) 
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5468) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

locationTrack object will be create when user click on detect button. locationTrack object is null when user go back without click on detect button.
So you have to put condition in onDestroy method like below:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if(locationTrack!=null)
       locationTrack.stopListener();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a bad designed code. Checking the `locationTrack` is null or not your responsibility.

And also, if you didn't click `detcbtn`, locationTrack will not be initialized and will cause same crash again.

Answer (score 0):

As Dhiren said, check nullability before stopListener or instantiate the object in `onCreate` method to ensure the object is not null.